# Pass file from JavaScript to Java Applet

Tags: java, javascript, file, applet

I'd like to manipulate some files using `JavaScript` and `Java`, but I don't have much experience with their interaction.

1. The first (`Java`) function is to download  video files using `JavaScript` and pass those into a `Java` applet to move them to the appropriate folder.
2. The second is to use the `Java` applet to retrieve specific video files from that folder, and feed them back into `JavaScript` to play them.

The `Java` applet is trivial to write (simply copying some files over or getting some files), but I'm not sure how to handle the interaction with `JavaScript`, as it's to my understanding that there's no equivalent "File" system in `JavaScript`. The video files will be stored in `JavaScript`, and they would be passed into the `Java` applet. Might I be able to take in Objects as my parameter in the `Java` applet, and try something like:

```
if(f instanceof File){
    ... do stuff as if it were a file
}
```

and do that for the copy function? I'm not sure how I'd be able to do the inverse though - returning a file from the applet to the `JavaScript` functions to be stored in some variable to make that video file accessible to the user.

Edit 1: By "the files will be stored in JavaScript", I meant that there will be variables in the `JavaScript` function containing all of the data for the video files.

Comment: "*The video files will be stored in JavaScript...*"  What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: I meant that JavaScript would have variables containing all of the data from the downloaded video files.